# Problems with serialization in a clustered environmnent

Tags: java, servlets, serialization, weblogic

I'm trying to use my Java application in a clustered environment with Weblogic 10 g, and we're having problems with session replication because a lot of classes that usually are in the session do not implement Serializable interface.

In one of these classes the problem is a ServletContext attribute that is not serializable. 
Am I correct in assuming this attribute should be marked with the transient keyword?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need it persisted you can mark it `transient` and the serialization will ignore it. Bear in mind that it will then be null when it's deserialized...

Comment: But why would I need it persisted? I don't know the implications of this, when the session is replicated. Will the user lost the session and need to log in again? What I'm actually trying to do is to replicate the session to a new node in the cluster without making the user loose its session having then to log in again.

Comment: You almost certainly don't as the ServletContext will obviously be different from server to server. I would even go as far as to say that having a pointer to it shows bad design. However if you do need a pointer to it you will need to reset it when the object is deserialized by implementing `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois)` to carry out custom actions.